# Angular show array values in one array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have array which values look like this in image

[image]

I need to convert in one arry like
{ "1vwxnrjq", "dasdada", "adsdadsada"} like this

```
console.log(items);
this.ids = items.id;
console.log(this.ids);
```

I am doing like this but its showing undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the easiest solution will be to just use the map function

```
console.log(items.map(r=>r.id))
```

```js
const items=[{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}];
console.log(items.map(r=>r.id));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like follows, first convert all into lowercase and then pick the length of substring you want. From below you can replace `9` with a variable value to get the length of substring you want.

```
temp = arr.map((item)=>{
  return item.id.toLowerCase().substr(0,9);
})
```

**Working snippet:**

```js
arr = [{id:"dafSDFdDfdafd"},{id:"adfdDFAsssd"},{id:"12adfdDFAsssd"}];

temp = arr.map((item)=>{
  return item.id.toLowerCase().substr(0,9);
})

console.log(temp);
```